# Division of losses

Tags: fair-division

Partner A borrows 40000 and invests in business. Partner B borrows 15000 and invests in same business. The business didnt go through.
Both Parties invested a total of 55 000. One partner invested more than other. He demands from partner B to share losses equally. Since Partner A invested more, he asks Partner B to reimburs him so the losses are shared 50:50.

How much partner B owes Partner A based on amount invested. What is the formula for calculation ?

Comment: **Step 1:** Name your variables! (What do you already know? What are you trying to figure out?) Feel free to draw a picture.
**Step 2:** How can you use what you already know to figure out what you want to find out? Write down a formula that you might use. **Step 3:** Take a shot at it. **Step 4:** Check your results. Go back to step 2 or 3 if necessary. **Step 5:** If you're stuck somewhere in steps 2-4, post your efforts here.

Comment: This isn't clear at all.  Why shouldn't $B's$ losses be capped at the $15,000$ investment?  What rule is to be followed?

Comment: Both Parties invested a total of 55 000. One partner invested more than other. He demands from partner B to share losses equally. Since Partner A invested more, he asks Partner B to reimburs him so the losses are shared 50:50. How to calculate how much should partner B pay to Partner A.

Comment: Please edit your post to include all the information.  There's nothing in what you wrote that suggests that losses should be split equally.

Comment: In any case:  if the total loss is $X$, then both parties need to put in $\frac X2$.  If, say, $\frac X2$ turned out to be $30000$ then $B$ would have to put in another $15000$, and so on.

Comment: I think it's very unlikely that your edit reflects the question author's intent. They wouldn't share profits 50-50, they would share them in proportion to their ownership stakes.

Comment: agreed. Partners would not share profits 50:50 but they would share them based on the ownership stakes. But the losses would be shared equally 50:50.

Comment: That's extremely unlikely.  Nobody would ever take that deal.  I think you have misunderstood the problem.

Comment: @lulu I don't think you are supposed to ignore the loss of the original investment.  I think it means that Partner B pays the first 25,000 of the amount owing, and debts in excess of $25,000$ are shared equally.

Comment: Ok let me rephrase it differently. Partner A invested 72% of the total amount. (40000/55000*100). Partner B invested 28% (15000/55000*100). How much the partner B has to pay to partner A to share losses 50:50 of the original investment of 55 000. Ignore the likelihood.

Comment: @saulspatz  No...I didn't ignore that.  If, as in my scenario, the total loss was $X=60,000$ then each of $A,B$ would be responsible for $\frac X2=30000$.  Thus, $B$ should pay in $15000$ more, and $A$ should take out $10,000$.

Comment: @lulu Right.  I misread your comment.  Sorry.

Comment: @lulu i think you are right. If i understood you correctly 55 000 / 2 = 27 500. Partner B invested 15 000. So he needs to pay remainder of 12 500 (27 500 - 15 000). Does this make sense ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  And that money is paid out to $A$.  And I trust that $B$ will never again do any business with $A$.

Comment: correct on both points. :):)  Thanks